# Vim exclusively make i enter insert mode

Tags: vim

My Vim setup has it (by default) so that non-<kbd>i</kbd> keys will enter insert mode. This includes <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>s</kbd> among others.

Is there a setting to make <kbd>i</kbd> exclusively enter insert mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no other way than remap all commands that start insert mode.

Comment: Do you know where I could find a list of these?

Comment: @Ge0rges you would need to look through manual in `:h normal-index` and `:h visual-index` as there is hell lot of different ways to enter insert mode (and one that you cannot disable `:startinsert`). However my main question would still be valid - **why?**